# displaying temp file from temp folder to image control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net form. In that iam uploading one file and it is storing in temp folder as file.tmp. I want to display that file in to image control in my form.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: image file is saved as temp file . now i want to save this temp file to another folder as image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to display that file in to image control in my form.

Assuming you have the file in `Data` folder

Use this :

```
  MyImg.ImageUrl=ResolveClientURL("~/Data/File.tmp")
```

Comment: temp folder is not inside my project. it is c:\document and setting\

Comment: @rahulkadachira Images should be served from client  from an accessible location (web location). you must make the location accessible and put it in your web project.

Comment: i changed to the folder in my project. now it is working. thanks

Comment: Don't store images in DB. store their path/url. But that's another question which you should ask.

Comment: and how to store this tmp file as image file in another folder

Comment: You have many answers [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=save%20uploaded%20images%20saveas&es_th=1)

Comment: i dont want to store it as tmp file. i want to store is as an image file